# MS Word automation error when trying to replace bookmark with excel cell content

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

The goal of my code is to find bookmarks throughout a word document and replace the information with the clients' name, address, or appraisal amount. My code searches for a bookmark containing certain information (for example the bookmarks look like [name], [address], [appraisal]) then it replaces it with information in a specific cell in an excel sheet. I want the code to look at all bookmarks throughout the document and replace it with the appropriate information and keep the bookmarks. There are two issues with the code. One, it says improper use of "Me" (referring to the Me.Repaint portion of the code). and if I try to run the code without the Me.Repaint i get a VBA run-time error'-2146959355 (80080005)': Automation error. Does anyone have any suggestions on what i could do differently? thank you

I have tried removing me.repaint and I have tried restarting word. I also have excel objects turned on in the VBA references section.

```
Function Read_Excel_Cell(cellRin As Long) As String
Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim myWB As Excel.Workbook
Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
Set myWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("excel file")
Read_Excel_Cell = myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(cellRin, 1)
Set myWB = Nothing
Set oExcel = Nothing
End Function

Sub clientinfoexcel()
Dim bmk As Bookmark
For Each bmk In ActiveDocument.Range.Bookmarks
cltext = bmk.Name
Dim clinfo1 As Range
Set clinfo1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(cltext).Range
If clinfo1.Text Like "*name*" Then
    clinfo1.Text = Text: Read_Excel_Cell (1)
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add cltext, clinfo1
ElseIf clinfo1.Text Like "*address*" Then
    clinfo1.Text = Text: Read_Excel_Cell (2)
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add cltext, clinfo1
ElseIf clinfo1.Text Like "*appraisal*" Then
    clinfo1.Text = Text: Read_Excel_Cell (3)
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add cltext, clinfo1
End If
Next bmk
End Sub
```

there is an automation error.

Comment: Setting myWB and oExcel = nothing doesn't close the workbook or quit excel, so you likely have a bunch of hidden excel instances open - check in Task Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting myWB and oExcel = nothing doesn't close the workbook or quit excel, so you likely have a bunch of hidden excel instances open - check in Task Manager.

A single open/close is all you need to grab the data you want.

For example(untested):

```
Sub clientinfoexcel()
    Dim bmk As bookmark, arrData
    Dim clinfo1 As Range, txt As String

    arrData = ReadExcelData()

    For Each bmk In ActiveDocument.Range.bookmarks
        txt = bmk.Range.Text

        If txt Like "*name*" Then
            SetBookMarkText bmk, arrData(1, 1)
        ElseIf txt Like "*address*" Then
            SetBookMarkText bmk, arrData(1, 1)
        ElseIf txt Like "*appraisal*" Then
            SetBookMarkText bmk, arrData(1, 1)
        End If
    Next bmk
End Sub

'Set the text in a bookmark without destroying it
Sub SetBookMarkText(bmk As bookmark, txt As String)
    Dim nm, rng
    nm = bmk.Name
    Set rng = bmk.Range
    rng.Text = txt
    rng.Parent.bookmarks.Add nm, rng
End Sub

'return Excel data as a 2-d array
Function ReadExcelData()
    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim myWB As Excel.Workbook
    Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
    Set myWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("excel file")
    ReadExcelData = myWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A10").Value 'for example
    myWB.Close False 'don't save
    oExcel.Quit
End Function
```

Comment: i tried the code that you provided and i was running into an error of ByRef argument type mismatch. Also, for some reason the set oExcel = New Excel.Application is causing word to stop responding and then a run time error: automation error

Comment: I'm away from a PC for a few days - can take a look when I get back.

Comment: I added a variable declaration for `txt As String` - that was likely the cause of the type mismatch error.  As for the issue with `et oExcel = New Excel.Application` - that works for me so I'm not sure what the problem might be on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `Me.Repaint` in the code in the question which is supposedly causing an error...? Is this being run from a UserForm? As far as I know, that's not part of Word or Excel...

In any case, there is a syntax error three times in the code on these lines:

```
clinfo1.Text = Text: Read_Excel_Cell (1)
```

This is incorrect: `Text:`

I believe what you wanted to have is:

```
clinfo1.Text = Text:= Read_Excel_Cell(1)
```

To specify a parameter `:=` is required, not `:`.

Beyond that, the code could be a bit more efficient. There's no need to repeat `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks[index]` when the`For` loop already provides the `bmk` object for the bookmark. And in my opinion, `Select Case` is easier to read, write an maintain than a lot of `ElseIf` statements.

I've also changed the code for Excel so that it only starts a new instance of Excel once - if it can't find Excel running. There'd be various ways to handle what you're trying to do with the Excel application - this is just one possibility. If you want to explore that further, I suggest more research (there a lots and lots of questions and code examples here and elsewhere) and maybe a different, more narrowly targeted question on that subject.

```
Function Read_Excel_Cell(cellRin As Long) As String
  Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
  Dim myWB As Excel.Workbook

  On Error Resume Next
  Set oExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Appplication")
  If Err.Number = 429 Then
    Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0

  oExcel.Visible = True
  For Each myWb in oExcel.Workbooks
    If myWb.Name = "excel file" Then
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

  If myWb Is Nothing Then
    Set myWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("excel file")
  End If

  Read_Excel_Cell = myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(cellRin, 1)
  Set myWB = Nothing
  Set oExcel = Nothing
End Function

Sub clientinfoexcel()
  Dim bmk As Bookmark
  For Each bmk In ActiveDocument.Range.Bookmarks
    cltext = bmk.Name
    Dim clinfo1 As Range
    Set clinfo1 = bmk.Range
    Select Case cltext
       Case Like "*name*"
            clinfo1.Text = Read_Excel_Cell(1)
            ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add cltext, clinfo1
       Case Like "*address*" 
            clinfo1.Text = Read_Excel_Cell(2)
            ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add cltext, clinfo1
       Case Like "*appraisal*" Then
           clinfo1.Text = Read_Excel_Cell(3)
           ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add cltext, clinfo1
    End Select
  Next bmk
End Sub
```